# Evaluate the integral along the given curve

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

[image]

I split each path into a separate integral, parametrized each path, then got stuck when I realised I had to replace $\text{d}x$ with $\text{d}t$.

Path 1 is from (0,1) to (0,0), path 2 is from (0,0) to (1,0), and path 3 is from (1,0) to (0,1).

Path 3 I have no issue with, the equation is $y=1-x$, I set $x=t$ and therefore $y=1-t$. I can then differentiate both of those to find $\text{d}x=\text{d}t$ and $\text{d}y=-\text{d}t$.

For path 1, $x=0$ and $y=t$, $\text{d}x=0$ and $\text{d}y=\text{d}t$, then I substitute these into the integral and both terms are zero. The same occurs for path 2, I have a feeling I am doing something wrong due to the nature of my answer. Usually when questions result this way it shows I'm doing it wrong. Is this approach correct or incorrect?

Comment: The line integral is indeed zero along $x$ and $y$ axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need split your integral into 3 integral: $I_1, I_2, I_3 $.

Path 1: $y=const =0$, so $dy = 0: \space I_1 = \int_0^1{0 dx} = 0$

Path 2: $y=1-x$, so $dy = -dx: \space I_2 = \int_1^0{(1-x)dx + xdx} = \int_1^0{(1-x + x)dx} = \int_1^0{dx}=-1$

Path 3: $x=const=0$, so $dx = 0: \space I_3 = \int_1^0{-0dy} = 0$

$I=I_1 + I_2 + I_3=-1$